# CodeIgniter Encryption different result

Tags: php, codeigniter, encryption, continuous-integration, password-encryption

I am trying to create some verification key for my application so it will generate some key in the encrypted form, but the problem is when i try using it in the xampp server it give different encryption result than it mean to be.

this is my code :

```
# Create PIN
        $length = rand(4, 4);
        $use_upper_case=false;
        $selection = '1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';     
        $pin = "";
        for($i=0; $i<$length; $i++) {
            $current_letter = $use_upper_case ? (rand(0,1) ? strtoupper($selection[(rand() % strlen($selection))]) : $selection[(rand() % strlen($selection))]) : $selection[(rand() % strlen($selection))];            
            $pin .=  $current_letter;
        }             

        $url = $CI->config->item('app_name');
        $lock = '1234';
        $verification_code = $CI->encrypt->encode($url, $pin);

        write_file(FCPATH . 'system/temp/verification.dat', $verification_code);
        write_file(FCPATH . 'verification.txt', $CI->encrypt->encode($pin, $lock));
        chmod(FCPATH . 'system/temp/verification.dat', 0600);
```

this is what i got in my appserv server

```
ASUIcgZtAC0=
```

this is what i got in my xampp server

```
xhK8/+D+tawgD5+usbt5WpmOe5nDLvfg+jUOFNwI2MHgYQM3iM/oEGZ8Abmw3HCbv0aX/vA9bz9SKni+w20Y/g==
```

please help, thank you

Comment: What is the problem? You want your xampp string to be shorter? It may be caused of different platform.

Comment: i want my encryption result be the same, that's all

Comment: Please see `$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";` Are those keys same? (in config/config.php). What is the `$url`? Please show us both outputs (from localhost and from remote host).

Comment: the `$config['encryption_key'] = "YOUR KEY";` are the same and i dont think it will change anything since i use `$pin` as encryption key, the `$url` is the application name i set on the config, i already show you both of the output of the encryption from localhost and remote host

Answer (score 0):

> i want my encryption result be the same, that's all

It sounds like you want a cryptographic hash function rather than encryption. [The difference isn't subtle](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/08/you-wouldnt-base64-a-password-cryptography-decoded).

Also, `rand()` is an insecure random number generator; you want `random_int()`.